# Extract previous issue id into youtrack report

Tags: youtrack

Is there a way to extract to a report previous issue ID after changing from one project to another?
Say Im opening ISSUE on project A and get A-5
Later Ill be changing the issue from project A to project B and get B-13.

Is there a way to extract both A-5 and B-13 to a report in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.